# Change the index of an item in an array by corresponding to html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm dynamically adding elements to a container and then using jquery UI to change the position of the dynamic elements and it works fine. The dynamic elements are constructed by looping through an array. What I want to achieve is, when I change the position of the dynamic element I also want to change the array items index to the corresponding value. What I tried below works when I move some of the dynamic elements to another position but messes up on others. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** long story short the numbers on the green block should be the same as the numbers in the array (same position too)

```js
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr;
};

let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  $('.container').append(`<div class="wrapper" id="${i}">${myArr[i]}</div>`)
}

let firstIndex;
let secondIndex;

$('.container').sortable({
  update: function(event, div) {
    firstIndex = div.item.attr('id')
  },
  stop: function(event, div) {
    secondIndex = div.item.index()
    array_move(myArr, firstIndex, secondIndex)
    console.log(myArr)
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 8vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

**UPDATE2:** This is a working version of my question. Any improvement is appreciated.

```js
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr;
};

let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  $('.container').append(`<div class="wrapper" id="${i}">${myArr[i]}</div>`)
}

$('.container').sortable({
  stop: function(event, div) {
    let elemId = div.item.attr('id')
    let elemIndex = div.item.index()

    array_move(myArr, elemId, elemIndex)

    $('.container').html(``)
    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
      $('.container').append(`<div class="wrapper" id="${i}">${myArr[i]}</div>`)
    }

    console.log(myArr)
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 8vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Don’t store data in two places (the dom elements and separately the array).  You should be able to retrieve the relevant values from the dom elements.

Comment: @James I am doing that because I have a different reason. I will add the working version of my approach to my question though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the ID of the index instead of the content of the array.

Here is a version that can handle Object arrays

```js
let myArr = [{
    "item": 0
  },
  {
    "item": 1
  },
  {
    "item": 2
  },
  {
    "item": 3
  }
];
const orgArr = myArr.slice(0); // copies a simple onedimentional array
const $container = $('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  $container.append(`<div class="wrapper" data-orgindex="${i}"></div>`)
}


$container.sortable({
  stop: function(event, div) {
    const sortOrder = $(".wrapper").map(function() {
      return this.dataset.orgindex
    }).get();
    myArr = sortOrder.map(idx => orgArr[idx])
    console.log(sortOrder, myArr)
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 8vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Please delete the other comments then